# How can I get boost to compile for an earlier deployment target on OSX?

Tags: macos, boost

this question has been asked before, but none of the answers seem to be currently working.. whether that's because they are incomplete, or things have changed, I don't know.

I build my code for a deployment target of 10.7 (my clients use their machines for music production, so they often prefer to stick with what they know works rather than updated with every new OS release).

I'm using boost.

So when I buid I get a bunch of warnings

```
ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(path.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being linked (10.7)
ld: warning: object file (/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a(error_code.o)) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being linked (10.7)
```

and so on.

So, I want to build boost (version 1.58 currently, unfortunately cmake is usually a couple of versions behind in what it can find) for a deployment target of 10.7

It seems the magic instruction is

macosx-version-min=10.7

except I can't make it work.

```
./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 -a macosx-version-min=10.7 install
```

Just doesn't do it, nor do any of the other things I've tried (I'm not familar with how b2 works, so I'm grasping in the dark).

I expect I'm missing something simple, but some help would be much appreciated

regards

Jon

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and could only fix it by building boost with the 10.7 library. I've used XCode 8.2.1. Here is what I did:

1. Modifying "Darwin.Jam". Look for this line: `feature macosx-version-min : : propagated optional ;` 
   and add this line below `feature.extend macosx-version-min : 10.7 ;`
2. Modify "Info.plist" in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform` and set `<key>MinimumSDKVersion</key>
   <string>10.11</string>`
3. Make sure your XCode.app has the 10.7 SDK installed. This is the right location: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs` You can extract or copy it from an earlier version of XCode.
4. Now build boost with these options: `cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk"`

E.g. `./b2 -a cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk"`

The solution above will build Boost with the 10.7 SDK instead just setting the Target SDK to 10.7